# Humoristic book about Jesus' brother and an AI

Tags: story-identification, religion, artificial-intelligence

I remember the description as follows:

- Jesus and God Christ (Christ is used as a family name) go on a holiday (golf, maybe?) and leave an AI in charge of creation
- Jesus' brother (Kevin Christ?) is insulted at not being left in charge and argues with the computer.
- Jesus' brother decides he can run things just fine and starts pushing some buttons on the computer, which naturally wreak havoc all around Creation.

It might be by Terry Pratchett, or else someone who would have a similar style (with apologies to true Pratchett fans who will say that there is no one else with "a similar style").

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is *Only Human* by [Tom Holt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Holt).

God and his elder son go fishing in some other galaxy, leaving younger son Kevin Christ at home. Mainframe, the extremely powerful computer, pretty much runs everything anyway.

Kevin figures out how to bypass Mainframe's blocks and can issue commands by pressing keys. The thing is, Mainframe doesn't have a manual (God is omniscient, so there's no need), and is blocked from providing Kevin with any useful information, but cannot resist the effect of pressing keys. So, as Kevin types blindly, hijinks issue.

The hijinks include several body swaps between humans, animals, machines, demons and paintings. Also the Sun going off for a bit. Nothing much, really. Just a slight glitch. Nothing to worry about, Dad.

<sub>What? How dare you say Tom Holt and Terry Pratchett have a similar style!!!!!</sub>

Comment: They're both... great? Is greatness a style?

Comment: I think I would have enjoyed Tom Holt's books more if I'd never read any Terry Pratchett. They're good, but... :)